# Fluent NHibernate export int/sbyte/byte length ignored

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm doing a project in C# using Fluent NHibernate. To make things easy, I make it auto generate the database using the mappings added. I got this mapping:

```
Table("sometable");
LazyLoad();
Id(x => x.Id).Column("id").Length(11).GeneratedBy.Identity();
Map(x => x.Name).Column("name").Length(20).Not.Nullable();
Map(x => x.Count).Column("count").Length(2).Not.Nullable();
```

And I got this:

```
public virtual int Id { get; set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
public virtual sbyte Count { get; set; }
```

In my entity class. The export code is:

```
.ExposeConfiguration(config =>
{
    new SchemaUpdate(config).Execute(false, true);
})
```

Now, the length of `Name` is taken correctly, however, my sbyte will always get length 4, my int always length 11, no matter what I set as `Length(..)`.

Why doesn't it take my length?

Answer (score 0):

`sbyte` is mapped to `DbType.SByte` which actual size in DB is vendor specific (may consume more, while being still only 1 byte in capacity). Same for `int`, mapped to `DbType.Int32`, 4 bytes in capacity.

Those types are not meant for having their size specified and trying to set their length is ignored. This is not a NHibernate limitation, but those types limitation. A byte is a byte, it cannot have any other size in capacity than one byte. `int` in C# is always 4 bytes (even if running x64) in capacity.

Maybe are you mistakenly using `int` and `sbyte` instead of `decimal`, which scale and precision may be specified (but not its length, which will be DB vendor specific).

Comment: No, I need to specify the user level (like user rank), my code above is just an example. The user rank can't be more than 2 numbers long so I thought I could just set length on 2.

Comment: What you want is then a `decimal(2,0)` (SQL Server syntax). Two digit, no fractional part. Other than using a `decimal` like type, there are no solution for enforcing in database only through the type your business constraint of no more than 2 digits. If you want to use binary based types such as `int` and `sbyte`, they will be constrained only to their capacity, which has nothing to do with base 10 digits. You then have to write your own code for enforcing your rule, either in your app or as trigger in database or whatever else.

Comment: So - and don't take this bad - you're saying I'm almost forced to use decimal or else it's not possible? I guess decimal is okay, but in my application it's 128 bit (decimal = 128 bit AFAIK) which is like.. hmm, A LOT more than what I actually need. Isn't that really bad itself?

Comment: You are forced to nothing. Just do some choices. Do you actually need to constrain that field to two digit in database? Then either use decimal(2, 0) or put some check contraint or trigger in the db for raising errors. If you do not actually need such a strong check, just stay simple, use an `int` (do not even bother using a `byte`, in most cases it will not be cheaper than `int` due to memory alignments), and let your application checking it remains in your required range.

Comment: About whether `decimal` memory size in .Net is bad or not for a two digit number, that depends on the application. In most cases that will not have any measurable impact. Your application would have to manipulate a big quantity of such "over-sized" variables for this to have any measurable impact. `decimal` may also be slower for some computation, but that matters too only for application doing lot of computation with those variables.